# Solr as analytics reporting platform

Tags: solr, analytics

I was trying to use Solr to develop a reporting platform. It is helping in merging data from all different sources and finally rich query API to create report. There are some analytical requirements too. Most of the cases are taken care of except two following scenarios

1. **Pivoting + Range facets** : Example use case : If we want to get number of US citizens, Non-US citizens visited europe each year. In collection there is flag USCitizen and date visitedOn.
2. **Faceting on functional query value** : If I have createdDate, closedDate. Then I calculate number of days between them using functions. On that calculated number of days value, would like to have faceting.

Any help with above two cases is really helpful to determine if Solr suites for the need.

Comment: The [JSON Facet API should be able](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceted+Search) to answer the first one? For the latter one I'd recommend indexing the result of the function as a field in the document - speeding up analytics by precomputing as much as possible is usually a good idea.

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks. Yes JSON Facet API can take care of first one if in nested facets both are fields. But I couldn't find a way to provide range and inside that another field. Like in example date-range at top and under that citizenship flag. Regarding second one, one I gave is one example. If I have 10 date fields, there so many combinations two date fields. If it is fixed set then pre-computing is option. But as a reporting platform, new fields and new combinations is possible.

Comment: I'd think you can use a new `facet` field under the range facet as shown in the examples where sub-facets are used? I.e. just another `facet:{ ... }` definition.